# how to get hourly calculation based on earliest pickup time and earliest stoptime

Tags: sql-server

how to get the hourly calculation according to the earliest start time and earliest stop time.
the condition is if the driver has the same name of drop address. the hourly calculation will show for all. The 0.00hrs should apply to all riders with the same drop address regardless of how many in the same ride. I attached a screenshot and which type of output I needed it's shown in highlighted areas. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leKAU.png)

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to calculate the number of minutes or seconds between start and end times and divide it by 60 or 3600 to get the hours.

Answer (score 0):

Why using XPathSelectElements in c# try give me some example. and try to give me Xdocument all method what is the work and some example?

Answer (score 0):

After creating date first approach Entity framework how to add table columns, a procedure from an existing database in ENTITY Fream work